# F#: Handling web exceptions

Tags: asynchronous, f#, system.net.webexception

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

Here are the relevant snippets of my code:

```
let downloadHtmlToDiskAsync (fighterHtmlDirectory: string) (fighterBaseUrl: string) (fighterId: int) = 
    let fighterUrl = fighterBaseUrl + fighterId.ToString()
    try 
        async {

            let! html = fetchHtmlAsync fighterUrl
            let fighterName = getFighterNameFromPage html

            let newTextFile = File.Create(fighterHtmlDirectory + "\\" + fighterId.ToString("00000") + " " + fighterName.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
            use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
            file.Write(html) 
            file.Close()
        }
    with
        :? System.Net.WebException -> async {File.AppendAllText("G:\User\WebScraping\Invalid Urls.txt", fighterUrl + "\n")}

let downloadFighterDatabase (directoryPath: string) (fighterBaseUrl: string) (beginningFighterId: int) (endFighterId: int) =
    let allFighterIds = [for id in beginningFighterId .. endFighterId -> id]
    allFighterIds
    |> Seq.map (fun fighterId -> downloadHtmlToDiskAsync directoryPath fighterBaseUrl fighterId)
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I have tested the functions fetchHtmlAsync and getFighterNameFromPage using F# Interactive. They both work fine.

When I build and run the solution, however, I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in FSharp.Core.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What went wrong? What changes should I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `try` `with` inside the `async`.

```
let downloadHtmlToDiskAsync (fighterHtmlDirectory: string) (fighterBaseUrl: string) (fighterId: int) = 
    let fighterUrl = fighterBaseUrl + fighterId.ToString()
    async {
        try
            let! html = fetchHtmlAsync fighterUrl
            let fighterName = getFighterNameFromPage html

            let newTextFile = File.Create(fighterHtmlDirectory + "\\" + fighterId.ToString("00000") + " " + fighterName.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
            use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
            file.Write(html) 
            file.Close()
        with
            :? System.Net.WebException -> File.AppendAllText("G:\User\WebScraping\Invalid Urls.txt", fighterUrl + "\n")
    }
```

Comment: haha yeah I was just commenting the exact same thing on your answer

Comment: Thanks, albertjan! It turns out that I was an idiot... I originally wrote my code the way you did, but because I forgot to rebuild my solution, I kept getting an error message, which prompted me to start making unnecessary and inaccurate changes. Now I have just rebuilt, and everything works great. Thanks again for your help. :-)

Comment: That happens to the best of us :)